# Gif Loading Flutter

Tags: flutter, gif, animated-gif

I am using ImageNetwork for loading the gif but its getting cropped after one complete circle .
The same gif working fine in android natively.

Here is the code i am using :

```
Image.file("gif_url",
                  height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(250),
                  width: ScreenUtil.screenWidthDp,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)
```

Below is the link of the result video of the gif i am getting.

With Flutter i am getting this result:

[image: With Flutter i am getting this result]

With Native i am getting this result:

[image: With Native Android i am getting this result]

I want the same result as in Native one.

Please let me know how can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

try Image.asset like following:

```
Image.asset(
                  AssetUtils.loader // path to gif file,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                  height: MediaQueryUtils(context).height * 0.1,
                  width: MediaQueryUtils(context).height * 0.1,
                ),
```

Comment: What's the errror now?

Comment: same thing as showing in the video above for flutter case icon crop in second rotation

Comment: Can you check if your state is changing at the time of gif is running and getting reset. I think this might be the issue, else the code should run fine.

Comment: nope its not state change issue i have tested on fresh page where no state getting changed